# Javascript "any string" regex in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, regex, handlebars.js, metacharacters

I am trying to compare a String with another one which contains a regex in Handlebars, and I am wondering if is there any meta character I can use to represent any String.

In other words, I want that the word "Resource" in the following snippet can be anything:

```
{{#if_eq blockReason compare="Unable to open [Resource]" }}
            ...do stuff...
{{/if_eq}}
```

Thanks in advance people!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2):

something that can represent any character would be this: `[\s\S]` This will match any character including newlines. If you want any character without newlines `.` will work just fine.

If you want to match a number of these character you can do this: `[\s\S]+`

Comment: I am using {{#if_eq blockReason compare="Unable to acquire lock, already locked by [\s\S]+" }} and it's not working unfortunately...

Comment: @stackpepe could you give us more detail in what you're trying to do?